# Add dropdownlist in search textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add drop down list to my textbox for searching for users. i.e, I want the dropdownlist to be inside the textbox for searching for users.
here is what I have now.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <p>        
      City: @Html.DropDownList("UserCity", "All")
      Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") @Html.CheckBox("IsActive") Active Users               
     <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </p>            
}
```

The problem here is that the city is showing up above the textbox for searching but I want it in it like Amazon search feature.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't simply place these elements inside each others. Period.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.bootply.com/64302)?

Comment: You will need to develop your own control or use a jquery autocomplete control. [Example here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: @Invent-Animate Yes, but I need it with it having "usercity" because I used that in my userscontroller

Comment: @AyoFafore Are you familiar with Bootstrap?

Comment: not so much but I think I can get it to work. Thank you. @Invent-Animate

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for autocomplete, not a dropdown list in a textbox

Here are two good tutorials that will help you with this

[mvc tutorial 1](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html)

[mvc autocomplete tutorial](http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/JQuery-UI/ASP-.NET-MVC-Autofill-Textbox.html)

Comment: She/he also may have been looking for something like `<datalist>`?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a drop down list in or beside the searchbox. 
The solution for what I was looking for was this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get))
{         

      <div>  
               <div style="float: left; width: 300px; text-align: left;">            
           @Html.Label("SearchString", "Find By Name")
           @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
           </div>
               <div style="width:300px; margin: 0.5em 0 0 0; overflow:auto;">
           @Html.Label("UserCity", "City")
           @Html.DropDownList("UserCity", "All")
                   </div>
           <div style="margin: 0.5em 0 0 0; overflow:auto";>
           @Html.CheckBox("IsActive") Active Users                       
           <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
                   </div>
           </div>
```

}

Comment: I think the `<datalist>` element is what you're looking for. Sure, you could make a `<div>`, but this element does it for you (since you were tagging your question with html5). Look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/datalist) to learn more about it.